# Colored Triangles Riddle

Tags: java, optimization, time, graph-theory

The riddle I'm hoping to solve can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukUPojrPFPA).

In case you're unable to watch the whole video, here is an outline of the riddle:

[image]

In short, I need to find the smallest number of points where there is guaranteed to be at least one single-color triangle from any arrangement of red and blue lines connecting every single pair of points.

Below is a Java program I wrote to solve it.

```
public class RedBlueTimeTravelProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 3;
        boolean alltri = false;
        long start, end;
        double time;

        while (!alltri) {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            int edgecount = max * (max - 1) / 2;
            int combos = (int) Math.pow(2, edgecount);
            alltri = false;

            for (int i=1; i<=combos; i++) {
                int a = i-1;
                int[][] edge = new int[edgecount][3];

                for (int j=0; j<edgecount; j++) {
                    edge[j][2] = a % 2;
                    a = (a - a % 2) / 2;
                }

                int c2 = 0;
                for (int j=1; j<=max; j++) {
                    for (int k=j+1; k<=max; k++) {
                        edge[c2][0] = j;
                        edge[c2][1] = k;
                        c2++;
                    }
                }

                boolean tri = false;
                for (int j=0; j<edgecount-2; j++) {
                    for (int k=j+1; k<edgecount-1; k++) {
                        for (int m=k+1; m<edgecount; m++) {
                            if ((edge[j][0] == edge[k][0] && ((edge[j][1] == edge[m][0] && edge[k][1] == edge[m][1]) || (edge[j][1] == edge[m][1] && edge[k][1] == edge[m][0]))) ||
                                    (edge[j][0] == edge[k][1] && ((edge[j][1] == edge[m][0] && edge[k][0] == edge[m][1]) || (edge[j][1] == edge[m][1] && edge[k][0] == edge[m][0]))) ||
                                    (edge[j][0] == edge[m][0] && ((edge[j][1] == edge[k][0] && edge[k][1] == edge[m][1]) || (edge[j][1] == edge[k][1] && edge[k][0] == edge[m][1]))) ||
                                    (edge[j][0] == edge[m][1] && ((edge[j][1] == edge[k][0] && edge[k][1] == edge[m][0]) || (edge[j][1] == edge[k][1] && edge[k][0] == edge[m][0])))) {
                                tri = tri || (edge[j][2] == edge[k][2] && edge[k][2] == edge[m][2]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                alltri = alltri && tri;
            }
            end = System.nanoTime();
            time = (end - start) / 1000000000.0;
            System.out.println(max + ": " + time + " seconds");
            max++;
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

}
```

It seems to work so far in checking whether 3, then 4, 5, etc. points will guarantee a single color triangle, but its time complexity is ridiculous. For example, here are the times for 3-8 points:

3: 1.8475E-5 seconds

4: 2.59876E-4 seconds

5: 0.009313668 seconds

6: 0.192455789 seconds

7: 19.226652708 seconds

Based on the trend, 8 points will take 30 min to 1 hr, 9 points will take roughly a few days, 10 will take over 6 months, and well... nobody wants to wait that long.

Any suggestions on how to make my program more time efficient?

Edit: Apparently the answer was 6. Not only was my code inefficient, it was just plain wrong. Also thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: I think you need to learn about pruning your search space. See if you can combine “prune” with some other relevant words in your search engine.

Comment: The basic idea is, each time you decide to try a red or a blue edge, immediately check if that forms a triabgle with other edges in the same colour, and back up if it does.